# npx expo prebuild --clean deleteall my node modules

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, npx, prebuild

So I used this command 'npx expo prebuild --clean'
cause Iwas tryna clear my cache to get my icon to change and it went and deleted my node modules and build files. What to do cause..

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the issue?.. If its only about `node_modules` then run `npm install` again and then create a build.